# Current Location updation on movement using google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using below code to show current location on google maps. But the problem is that if i am moving my location is updating again and again. For the first time loading i want to fix my current location on the map, after that if i am moving then i don't want to update it. I am selecting a point on the map, and if i am moving or after few seconds it again moves to my current location and don't allow user to select desired point. My code is given below, please help me out here.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Location lastLocation = null;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        float diff = 0;

        if (lastLocation != null) {
            diff = location.distanceTo(lastLocation);
        }

        if ((lastLocation == null) || (diff > 5)) {

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude());
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(latLng, 20,
                    45, 0);
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 2000, null);

            lastLocation = location;
        }

    }
};

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapVirard)).getMap();
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(Virtuvity.this);

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(Virtuvity.this);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
            mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                    LatLng latLng = arg0.target;
                    latitude = latLng.latitude;
                    longitude = latLng.longitude;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST, locationListener);
    }
};

private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
    if (mLocationClient == null) {
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(),
                connectionCallbacks, onConnectionFailedListener);
    }
}

OnConnectionFailedListener onConnectionFailedListener = new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: onLocationChanged will keep sending you new location with any minor movement of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Inside onLocationChanged if `location != null`

call `mLocationClient.removeUpdates(this);`